# is it possible reverse SHA1 hash to binary?

Tags: python, hash, binary, sha1

Given the byte size and SHA1 hash (20 bytes),
can binary data be generated to fit a given SHA1 hash?
For example, given a hash of 16KB size and A, a meaningless binary file with an A hash value is created.
Is it possible? If possible, in what direction can I write the code?

Comment: One of the points of cryptographic hashes like SHA1 is that it must be extremely difficult to generate a document with a given hash.

Comment: Also, there are "infinitely" many documents which share the same SHA1 (or any other) hash. You'd somehow have to specify which one of those documents you prefer over others.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a meaningful document. We just need trash data with the same hash value. Is it still impossible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, welcome to the league of bitcoin miners. The classic approach is to generate random documents until one of them fulfills your condition. If your condition is that the whole hash should be equal to what you want, you'll have to generate roughly `2^160` documents (which is a lot). Brute-forcing the solution would probably be unfeasible for you.

Check [this link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47177/would-sha1-be-broken-by-sheer-brute-force-even-if-it-had-no-weaknesses-of-its-o) out instead, the answer features a link to a paper which discusses how to crack SHA1.

Why roughly `2^160` documents? Because if you indeed were to brute-force your way to the solution, you have no way to know beforehand if a document corresponds to your hash, so you just have to generate a random document, SHA1 it, look at the hash, and if it does not equal your target hash, try again. There are `2^160` SHA1 hashes, so you'd  need to generate `2^160` documents to search the whole space. You can of course get lucky; then, on average, you only need to generate `2^159` documents (if you find a specific ordering).

Comment: Why is it 2^20? I'd appreciate it if you could explain it.

Comment: My bad, I misread your definition of SHA1 (I thought you said 20 bits.) Nevermind.